# Is this too much memory for mysql on ubuntu?

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, ram, amazon-ec2

I had a question about mysql memory usage in a ubuntu server.

I have an AWS EC2 server that hosts about 20 wordpress sites, all conencted to 1 mysql instance. They aren't huge sites by any means, but they are crashing a bit because of memory usage.

I was checked out the memory usage with htop, and noticed a bunch of mysql threads that were spawned.

They mysql process is showing about 11.7% of memory usage. Is that typically too high? I recently added a swapfile to make sure the memory doesn't continue to crash, but I wanted to be sure that I have everything optimized.

[image: htop output]

```
free -m

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1998         766         547          99         684         937
Swap:          1023           5        1018
```

Thanks
Brendan

Comment: Pro tip: don't run anything else on the same machine as MySQL, particularly not Apache, which is notorious for hogging memory under load, and MySQL on the same server is commonly the *victim* in that scenario. It doesn't crash -- it gets killed:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/25077/11651

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for the tips Michael!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time you ran `free -m`, you had plenty of spare memory.  If that time was representative of normal or peak traffic, then I'd say you're fine, but if you did that at an idle or off-peak time it's hard to tell.

There are extensive guides on how to optimize MySQL memory usage and they depend on things like whether it's a server dedicated to MySQL (it isn't), whether you're primarily MyISAM or InnoDB or both, and so on.

On a server dedicated only to Wordpress (PHP and MySQL), it would be fine if MySQL memory use was at 60% or less, I would say.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip Thomas! I will monitor it